# Detecting increases in twitter list activity

Tags: time-series, data-visualization

I'm trying to find more information on how to measure and detect increases in activity in twitter list activity. I have access to all the tweets produced by a list of users. The idea is to try to predict or detect when there is some breaking news that everyone is talking about.

A sensible thing is to plot number of tweets over time, and proportion of active users in a list (if 10 out of 30 users in a list tweet, proportion of active users = 0.33)

The problem with this is that it is difficult to spot spikes in activity due to daily rhythm - people tend to sleep, and only tweet during the day... who knew?

A quick and dirty example: (Cycle plot?)
http://savedbythegoog.appspot.com/?id=6708dc9a2c90f9f937755542900a1b1957f20f3a

Looking at a month of data is slightly better - but not really informative:
http://savedbythegoog.appspot.com/?id=014b2246ba3d762b5201f0048812cd0675d5721a

Those peaks could be annotated with the top hashtags to give some meaning to them.

That's what I got so far.

Are there any specific things i could read up on to get a better measure or make things more interpretable? Any other approaches or ideas more than welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try modeling the "expected" behavior (like time-of-day fluctuations) with some model such as regression or exponential smoothing. Then, since you are interested in detection, I'd monitor the forecast errors using a statistical control chart. The control chart is based on putting threshold(s) on the forecast error, such that an extreme forecast will trigger an alert.